# Installing Arch Linux on empty eee pc's hard drive

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, hard-disk, asus

I have a problem with the installation of Arch Linux on an Asus 1000HD eee pc.

The fact is, it had a Windows XP home basic installation, and it was still very very slow with that.

So I formatted the hard drive and erased all partitions with Windows 7 Disk Manager (I used an old Toshiba external hard dtive case to connect my HD plug n play).

Than, i tried ISO to USB to install Arch Linux on that drive.

I also installed it to my usb pen drive with unetbootin.

Finally, I plugged the hard drive back to its place. Nothing happened.

I tried to boot the system via USB pen drive, still nothing happens (it didn't even power it).

I am pretty sure that I made some mistakes, and I read tutorials all over the internet, no one worked.

Could you help me?
Thank you!

Comment: *didn't even power it* sounds like a serious problem - like you've broken the computer.

Comment: Did you change your BIOS to boot from the USB key?

Comment: Yes, the bios is set to accept USBs before any other thing. I don't think my pc is broken, it worked fine before formatting the hard drive...

Comment: It didn't power the PC, or it didn't power the USB drive?

Comment: It didn't power the drive. The pc booted, and showed the "Insert bootable disk and press any key" message.

Comment: On my (not eee) machine I have to press a key at boot time to access the boot menu that will check the USB drive. Your's might do too, or it might only boot from a specific USB socket.

Comment: I did get into the bios, and tryed every combination of the showed drives; I also tryed to switch usb port, but nothing happened. Yet, if I plug in another laptop HD, the HD boots fine (slow but fine), but still no response from the usb drives. I am starting to think about a not-up-to-date BIOS problem... What do you think?

Comment: Just for the record, the Arch installation ISO is incompatible with `unetbootin` by default, and it is recommended that you not use it, but instead copy it directly to the USB with `dd`.